# NLP - Sentence Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am a newbie trying my hands on sentence segmentation in NLP.
I am aware tokenizers are available for the same in NLTK. But I wanted to build my own sentence segmenter using Machine Learning algorithm like Decision Tree. But I am not able to gather training data for it. How should be the data. How should it be labelled, since I wanted to try first using supervised learning. Any sample data already available? Any help will be useful. I searched in net for nearly a week and now posting the same for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Sentence splitters are typically implemented as a hybrid with a set of rules (the punctuation characters to consider) and some automatically learnt weights (for exceptions, such as abbreviations with a period, which don't act as a full stop). The weights can be learnt without supervision.

It's an interesting idea, however, to approach this with a plain ML-based system. For a supervised scheme, you could try a character-based sequence-labelling model with `BIO` labels. For example, your training data could look like this:

```
This is it! I'm leaving Dr. Smush in his box.
BIIIIIIIIIIOBIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

The predicted output will then also be `BIIIIO...`, and you'll have to split the original text at the characters labelled `O`.
I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but if you try it, let me know if it's any good. Make sure you use *n*-grams of high orders (3-, 4-, 5-grams or even higher), since these are characters, not word tokens.

As for the training data, you can use any linguistically annotated corpus, since they are all sentence-split (eg. look at the ones included in NLTK).
All you have to do is producing the `BIO` labels for training.

Answer (score 0):

As Lenz said the current sentence splitters are commonly a mix of regex or rule base approaches with unsupervised. For example, PunktSentenceTokenizer from nltk is based on unsupervised learning (Unsupervised Multilingual Sentence Boundary Detection) by learning the abbreviations from the text and avoiding segmentation when they appear. You can add your own abbreviations for a special corpus

The BIO approach looks more for a NER. In fact, this approach exists and you can find fine-tuned BERT's based on this approach or a similar like BILOU. Among DL models BERT is pretty friendly for this task since it comes with the tokens CSL and SEP to indicate the start and the end of the sentences. You can also train a segmentation splitter based on those tokens by yourself, but be careful with using those tokens directly since the SEP token is not purely the end of the sentence but end of a group of sentences. Morever for a big corpus this approach could be time-consuming.

The closer to what you said is a semisupervised learning with NaiveBayes that you can find here:
http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html
You can train your own splitter with your dataset but you need to split the data into sentences before training. So the label is implicit in the splits, semisupervised. This gives a 96-97 of accuracy, which is a good result. Decision Trees are more expensive and the result would not get much better. So if you want to adapt it to a special corpus at the end either you use regex or you add abbreviations to nltk. If you just want to play you can test with different classification models this approach and see the results.