# Perform sentence segmentation on paragraphs without punctuation?

Tags: algorithm, text, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I have a bunch of badly formatted text with lots of missing punctuation. I want to know if there was any method to segment text into sentences when periods, semi-colons, capitalization, etc. are missing. 
For example, consider the paragraph: **"the lion is called the king of the forest it has a majestic appearance it eats flesh it can run very fast the roar of the lion is very famous"**.
This text should be segmented as separate sentences:

- **the lion is called the king of the forest**
- **it has a majestic appearance**
- **it eats flesh**
- **it can run very fast**
- **the roar of the lion is very famous**

Can this be done or is it impossible? Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: You can train a sequence classifier. It's very easy to get tons of training material: use any corpus containing punctuation, perform sentence splitting, remove punctuation – voilà.

Comment: @lenz Which is the easiest way to create a sequence classifier in Python? Can you do this in NLTK?

Comment: Yes, NLTK has a [classification module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify). Typically, beginners are introduced to supervised machine learning with a Naive-Bayes classifier, which is conceptually pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @lenz What would be the input and the output of this classifier?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141113/nlp-sentence-segmentation/44144787#44144787) I posted recently.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the following `Python` implementation from [here](https://habr.com/en/post/581960/).

```
import torch

model, example_texts, languages, punct, apply_te = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models', model='silero_te')

#your text goes here. I imagine it is contained in some list

input_text = input('Enter input text\n') 
apply_te(input_text, lan='en')
```